# How can I disable Android SSO für Facebook App Center?

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, center

I submitted an Android and iOS App for the Facebook App Center.
Disabeling iOS SSO was no prob, but disabeling Android SSO was imposible. That's why I enabled it, although I don't use Facebook SSO in my apps. That was the only way I could submit my apps.
Facebook gave me following feedback on my submission:

> "Your Android app does not appear to use Single Sign-On (SSO). Please
>   either implement SSO or remove this integration as a listed platform
>   in the developer app."

I tried to remove the integration as suggested and it gave me this error message:

> You have specified an Android package to launch, but have not enabled
>   Configured for Android SSO. Only applications that support Android SSO
>   can be launched.

Did anyone else have this problem? What can you do?